# Wpf datagrid column size is not adjusted according to the width of the content present in rows

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

### Wpf datagrid column size is not adjusted according to the width of the content present in rows

We have one datagrid in wpf application.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvOrders" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Visible" Cursor="Hand"
       CanUserAddRows="False"
       ColumnWidth="Auto"
       FontWeight="Normal" 
       Margin="5,5,5,0" 
       AlternationCount="2" 
       DragOver="dgvOrders_DragOver" 
       Drop="dgvOrders_Drop"
       DragEnter="dgvOrders_DragEnter"
       AllowDrop="True"
       Height="Auto"
       MaxHeight="380"
       PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="dgvOrders_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
       SelectionMode="Extended" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" 
       HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFD8D8D8" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFD8D8D8"
       PreviewKeyDown="dgvOrders_PreviewKeyDown" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <DataGrid.RowStyle>
           <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDisposed}" Value="False">
                       <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                  </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgcRouteIndex" Binding="{Binding RouteOrderIndex, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Tour Reihenfolge" Width="Auto" Visibility="Hidden" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FullName, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Name" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address.Zip, Mode=OneWay}" Header="PLZ" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address.City, Mode=OneWay}" Header="ORT" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address.Street, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Straße" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BirthDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Geburtsdatum" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsChild, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToJaNeinConverter},Mode=OneWay}" Header="Kind" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsSecondVisit, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToJaNeinConverter},Mode=OneWay}" Header="Verzögerung" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DeadlineDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Fristdatum" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsNoCurePossible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToJaNeinConverter},Mode=OneWay}" Header="Anlass" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsSecondVisit, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToJaNeinConverter},Mode=OneWay}" Header="Gutachtenart" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OpinionDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Begutachtungsdatum" Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Info, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Info" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgcRouteDistance" Binding="{Binding RoutingDistance,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Kilometers" Width="Auto" Visibility="Hidden" CanUserResize="False"/>
           </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

We have functionality that on scrolling the mouse wheel by pressing control key, font size of text present in the application increases (Scroll Up : increase, Scroll Down : decrease).

When we scrolls up then font size of text present in the data grid row increases, and also the width of that respective columns increases.

**But when we scrolls down, font size of text present in the data grid row decreases, but column width does not decrease.**

Can anybody have the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this loop

```
foreach (ColumnHeader c in table.Columns)
{
    c.Width = -2;
}
```

Width -2 is adjusting width to content of header and cells.